# Matching in odd/even components

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G = (V,E)$ be a graph and let $S$ be a partition of the nodes $V$, $S \subseteq V$, such that it holds that $\nu(G) = \frac{1}{2}\left(|V| + |S| - oc(G-S)\right)$. Here $oc(G-S)$ is the number of odd components in the graph $G-S$ and $\nu(G)$ the cardinality of a maximum matching of $G$. It was stated that for this choice of $S$, which is a witness set since equality holds in Tutte-Berge's formula, the following statements hold, however I do not see why.

1. In every maximum matching, the nodes in $S$ are matched to nodes in different odd components of $G-S$.
2. Every even component of $G-S$ has a perfect matching.
3. Every odd component of $G-S$ has a matching with only one exposed node.

Can anybody help?

Comment: You can start with proofs of [Tutte theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tutte_theorem) and [Tutte-Berge formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tutte%E2%80%93Berge_formula).

Comment: I know that for a maximum matching $M$, the odd components of $G-S$ either have 1 $M$-exposed node, or M has an edge with 1 endpoint in such an odd component of $G-S$. However, why does the other endpoint have to be in $S$?

Comment: It seems I do not understand your question. If $S$ is a partition, then every node belongs to either $S$ or $V \setminus S$. So if only one endpoint belongs to $V \setminus S$, then the other has to be in $S$. Is that what are you asking about?

Comment: I am trying to prove the first statement. I am trying to work out why the nodes of $S$ must be matched to distinct odd components of $G-S$, and why it cannot be matched to an even component of $G-S$, where would this give a contradiction if you assumed this was in fact the case? Thanks.

Comment: If there was an edge between them (because $M$ has to use edges in $E$), then that would be one component, instead of two.

Comment: I understand, but why can't the matching $M$ have two distinct edges both matched to the same odd component?

Comment: I am sorry, but I do not understand what it is that you are asking about. Could you perhaps make a diagram?